# How to get server-side call to Google Places API to work?

Tags: google-places-api

I'm trying to get [Place Detail via Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) as follows:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJLQUUOYZZwokR1BfSFbM-XB4&key=<<KEY>>
```

but I keep getting the following error (both in browser and server-side):

```
{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

[image]

I created a brand new key without any restrictions (and Maps API is enabled in my google console). How do I get this to work??

[image]

Comment: You mention that the Maps API is enabled in your console, but your question is about the the Places API which is separate, did you enable that as well?

Comment: @Ezphares pls post this as an answer. I guess they only recently introduced it and I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Places API is separate from the Maps API. Make sure the Places API is enabled in the developer console as well.